# html/css: why does padding enlarge my div

Tags: html, css

i have the following markup:

```
<div
style="position:absolute;width:100px;height:100px;background-color:#ccc">     
    <div style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;background-color:#fcc;padding:50px;">

                TEST

    </div>
</div>
```

to my understanding the padding in the inner div should only move the position of the text and not enlarge the div itself. 
how can this be avoided? thanks!

Comment: The [box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html) states that padding *adds* to the size of a box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove width & height of child div. Padding adds its container's size.

Answer (score 0):

@clamp

you add padding on child div which means it's increase the height & width

example: `width=100% +50px +50px ,height=100% +50px +50px`

So, if you want to give padding then adjust width & height according to it
like example :
my div 
`height & width is 200px` .
 Then if i give
 `padding:50px;`

then i have to adjust height to `height & width is 100px`